# JupyterLab Extension Error : "Error communicating with server extension. Consult the documentation for how to ensure that it is enabled."

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, flake8

I am trying to install jupyterlab extensions such as [flake8](https://github.com/mlshapiro/jupyterlab-flake8) but cannot do any of that. I am able to install on the server side via pip but cannot install the client side extension. I go to the extension manager on the left, search for the extension (jupyterlab-flake8) and press "install" and then get

```
 "Error communicating with server extension. Consult the documentation for how to ensure that it is enabled.

Reason given:

Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

Any input into this would be very helpful.

I have ensured that I have installed jupyterlab and flake8 via pip through the terminal but I am not able to install this extension through the extension manager on jupyterlab.